# Prediction using RandomForest Algorithm, Sensitivity and Specificity

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, data-science

I'm new to ML and developing a simple Prediction model using Random Forest algorithm. I'm also evaluating my model using Confusion Matrix and computing the Sensitivity and Specificity scores of my built model.

While I conceptually understand these two, I'm now stuck at a point where my model always results in the sensitivity score of 1 and specificity score of 0. It gets an accuracy score of 91% (91/100 training samples are predicted correctly).

Now what do I infer from this? Is my model too sensitive and not specific? Will I have to understand that my model will be more bound to emit False Positives and never False Negatives? (This may be good in my scenario) as the domain I'm dealing with is predict frauds where false positives are better.

As a side note, on a typical ML workflow, how the Sensitivity and Specificity scores are often used in practise? Is it used to keep some sort of a threshold on the client systems to take the prediction with a pinch of salt? What would be the parameters I can tune to get different values for these? At the moment, I just tweaked the Random Forest model variables like no of trees, no of nodes etc. But these numbers always remain the same.

Comment: Y not plot ROC AUC curve?

Comment: I removed the "ML" tag, which concerns the ML programming language and nothing else.

Comment: AUC is 0.5 which is the worst possible number I guess

Comment: Also wondering how my accuracy is 90% and AUC is nothing more than a random probability

Comment: Because you are probably in a class imbalance setting, which requires special handling

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that the best inference you can make from your specificity and sensitivity numbers is that your model is somehow misspecified, there is a data error, or some other non-parameter aspect of the data or your code that is causing this problem.

As you know: (Using: True Positive, False Negative...)

```
Sensitivity = TP/(TP + FN) 

Specificity = TN/(FP + TN)

Accuracy = (TP + TN) / (TP + FP + TN + FN)
```

To get sensitivity = 1, TP = TP + FN. There are a number of ways that could happen, of course, but the ones to look for are TP = FN, or FN = 0 (since TP cannot be 0).

Additionally, a specificity of 0 implies that TN = 0, regardless of what FP and TN are. But here too I would look at the distribution of FP and TN.

If TN = 0, then for accuracy = 0.9 it must be that TP = 0.9, which suggests that even if TN = 0, FP and/or FN are > 0 and indeed that FP + FN = 0.1 (since the denominator must equal 1).

One possibility, mentioned by @desertnaut is that you have a serious class imbalance issue. That is, the minority class (the one you want to predict) is a very, very small fraction of the total number of all observations in your data. To look into this, simply plot the distribution of your target. If you're seeing that the minority class is less than, say, 10% of the total, (in general, one category dominates the other 10:1) then you're likely to start seeing problems in your model.

[Here's a good tutorial on dealing with imbalanced data.](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/)

[And here's a paper if you're more technically minded and want to confront an imbalance in a more academic way.](http://statistics.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/tech-reports/666.pdf)

That said, I would also look at the code you have for your model. Check into how you're separating training and testing:

- Is the balance of classes in the training set representative of the balance in the whole set?
- How are you doing cross-validation, if at all? Does changing the method give you different results for spec/sens?
- Are the data types for the categories correct throughout (and for the rest of the variables, for that matter)? Since RF can deal with categorical variables it might not throw an error if you have what you expect to be an `int` coded as a `string` (just to pick an example), which might produce odd results.

Seeing any results with perfect scores (1/0) is usually a sign that something other than just model parameters (or hyperparameters) is incorrectly specified. Not that it *can't* happen. It just so rarely does.